# Does the OS X app "Day One" support MathJax

Tags: macos, applications

I'd like to keep a professional journal of my thoughts. I have my eye on the app [Day One](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/day-one/id422304217?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D4). One reason for this is that it's based on Multimarkdown, which often means it includes support for equations in LaTeX. However, I don't know if this particular Markdown feature is supported in the Day One app.

If anyone has the app, you could test this for me by typing something like

```
$$ \int x\,dx = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C $$
```

and seeing if it comes out as a nice-looking equation.

[image]

(It is possible that "MathJax" might have to be enabled in some kind of preferences menu for this to work.) I looked for a demo version of the app, and since it's paid I wonder if someone has experience and if not, I can self-answer this once I get an email back from their customer support staff.

Does Day One have a way to typeset equations whether it's MathJax integration or another way?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33051/discussion-on-question-by-nathaniel-does-the-os-x-app-day-one-support-mathjax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Day One 1.10.2 does not appear to support MathJax. I entered the following:

```
$a$
$$a$$
\(a\)
\[a\]
a^2
```

This was rendered as…

[image]

I have looked through the Preferences, and whilst there is an Appearance tab, it provides no settings relevant to this. I've been unable to find any mention of LaTeX or MathJax in the menus or [help.dayoneapp.com](http://help.dayoneapp.com/).

Comment: The double $$ typically needs to be a block renderer - with newlines after the first $$ and before the second... What happens if you put the $$ on a line before and after the text the author quoted?

Comment: @bmike Hmm, I've never heard that before? It doesn't make a difference though, still not rendered.